# How to set files inside the assets folder in index.html

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I have a folder structure like below

- angular-src

  - src

    - index.html
- bootstrap
- css
- app.js

In my app.js file I have set this static folder like:

```
// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I want to set css and bootstrap files inside the index.html.

Here's `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Alpha Theme</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- styles -->
    <link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/stats.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="copy text-center">
          Copyright 2014 <a href='#'>Website</a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </footer>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendors/morris/morris.css">
<script src="./vendors/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="./vendors/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendors/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendors/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="./vendors/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
<script src="./vendors/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script src="./vendors/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="./vendors/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="./vendors/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script src="./js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="./js/stats.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

For directory structure :

- use single dot(.) for current directory
- use double dots(..) jump out the current directory

Now coming to your question to set path of your css and bootstrap files use in index.html :

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- styles -->
    <link href="../../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../css/stats.css" rel="stylesheet">
```